# Update custom field on the fly

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

In Woocommerce I want to update the custom field value for a logged in user. How can that be done?

Comment: who adds the custom field?

Comment: I have this custom field in the Product http://prntscr.com/l0qs3a . I wan't for a specific customer to raise this price (all prices of the products by 30%).